# How to revoke HealthKit Authorization

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

In my application, I am using a HealthKit, all going good.
Authorization done using this code

```
 NSArray *readTypes = @[
                    [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount],
                    [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate],
                    [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned]                           ];

    NSArray *writeTypes = @[
                   [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount],
                   [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate],
                   [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned]                            ];

    [self.healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:[NSSet setWithArray:writeTypes]
                                             readTypes:[NSSet setWithArray:readTypes] completion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                                 NSLog(@"Succes ==>%d",success);
                                                  NSLog(@"error ==>%@",error);
                                             }];
```

Now I want to revoke it, how ? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to revoke authorization programmatically. If you'd like to test the behavior of your app when authorization is revoked, uninstall the app and reinstall it, or tap the Reset Location & Privacy button in Settings > General > Reset.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily revoke it (and the rest of the cache) for the `#Preview` canvas using the following command line:

```
xcrun simctl --set previews delete all
```